Build fail with NASM and GoLink (Windows 11)
first I'm new to assembly langage i want to learn it, I am actually on Windows 11 (x64, Intel core I5 11400H), coding with Notepad, and for building step, i use NASM and GoLink.
The problem that i have is when i try to build my program (main.asm), i have the following error printed into my console :
`GoLink.Exe Version 0.26.14 - Copyright Jeremy Gordon 2002/9 - JG@JGnet.co.uk
Error!
The following symbols were not defined in the object file or files:-
MessageBoxA
ExitProcess
Output file not made`
The commands i use for building (inside compile.bat file located in the same folder as main.asm) are :
@echo off
nasm -f win64 main.asm -o main.obj
GoLink /entry main main.obj kernel32.lib user32.lib
pause

And finnaly, the asm code inside my main.asm file is :
section .data
    message db 'Hello World !', 0
    title db 'Greetings', 0

section .text
    global main
    extern MessageBoxA
    extern ExitProcess

main:
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, message
    mov rdx, title
    mov rcx, 0
    call MessageBoxA

    mov eax, 0
    call ExitProcess

I actually tried to :

Rename user32.lib and kernel32.lib to user32.Lib and kernel32.Lib

Change theses files to their absolute path
(Exemple C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.26100.0\um\x64\kernel32.Lib instead of     kernel32.lib)


I read that to resolve the problem, i must change "extern MessageBoxA" to "extern _MessageBoxA@(which i don't know what number to put here"
And same for ExitProcess (to _ExitProcess@4) but it don't work
Thank you in advance for your answer (ps : I'm french so sorry if my english is bad).

The Windows calling convention (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170) doesn't pass args in RDI / RSI; you were probably looking at x86-64 System V (Linux / Mac / everything else).  Also, _name@stack_arg_size is for 32-bit Windows stdcall; Windows x64 doesn't decorate function names with a leading underscore or trailing @.  See the linked duplicates for working code and build commands.

Thank you for your answer, i'll read the documentation about calling convention, so if i understand correctly, the asm code above is not for Windows ? then i'll try to look for another tutorial

MessageBoxA is a WinAPI function that only exists on Windows. So this code can't work anywhere.  It's also not reserving shadow space (which is technically ok since it doesn't try to ret).  If that's verbatim from a tutorial, at best the author had a brain-fart and didn't test their code (which is already very bad), or at worst the whole tutorial is total garbage from someone who doesn't know what they're talking about.  (A lot of tutorial are written by beginners as a learning exercise, and contain many misunderstandings, especially on sites like geeks4geeks.)
